# How to "convert n*n matrix to absolute matrix" and "calculate each row sum of absolute matrix" in python without numpy

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

example input: 
0 -1.2 2.5
1.2 0 -3.3
-2.5 3.3 0

output should be like below:
absolute matrix:
0 1.2 2.5
1.2 0 3.3
2.5 3.3 0
row sum matrix:
3.7 4.5 5.8

Answer (score 0):

Since your matrix are in the form of a nested list:

```
numbers = [[0, -1.2, 2.5], [1.2, 0, -3.3], [-2.5, 3.3, 0]]
```

For absolute numbers, map the function abs to each sublist of numbers. This will return a map object which is then converted to a list using the list function.

```
abs_numbers = [list(map(abs, i))for i in numbers]
```

For row sum, simply sum each sub-list in the abs_numbers list.

```
row_totals = [sum(i) for i in abs_numbers]
```

Comment: my input is in the form of [[0, -1.2, 2.5], [1.2, 0, -3.3], [-2.5, 3.3, 0]]  Input will be a n*n matrix